# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object in lemmatization nltk

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

Then these file has to be tokenized into sentences, then each sentence into word array, and that can be tagged by nltk tagger. With that lemmatization can be done, and then stemming added on top of it.
This code from ([How to provide (or generate) tags for nltk lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40568856/how-to-provide-or-generate-tags-for-nltk-lemmatizers))

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
    # use sent_tokenize to split text into sentences, and word_tokenize to
    # to split sentences into words
    from nltk.tag import pos_tag
    # use this to generate array of tuples (word, tag)
    # it can be then translated into wordnet tag as in
    # [this response][1]. 
    from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
    
    # code from response mentioned above
    def get_wordnet_pos(treebank_tag):
        if treebank_tag.startswith('J'):
            return wordnet.ADJ
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('V'):
            return wordnet.VERB
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('N'):
            return wordnet.NOUN
        elif treebank_tag.startswith('R'):
            return wordnet.ADV
        else:
            return ''    
    
    
    with open('filename.csv', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read()
        sentences = sent_tokenize(data)
        ignoreTypes = ['TO', 'CD', '.', 'LS', ''] # my choice
        sentence =[]
        lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
        for sent in sentences:
            words = word_tokenize(sentence)
            tags = pos_tag(words)
            for (word, type) in tags:
                if type in ignoreTypes:
                    continue
                tag = get_wordnet_pos(type)
                if tag == '':
                    continue
                lema = lmtzr.lemmatize(word, tag)
```

When I am trying to use above codes appear this error bellow and How to write the result to csv file?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b89f61d662a8> in <module>()
     29     lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
     30     for sent in sentences:
---> 31         words = word_tokenize(sentence)
     32         tags = pos_tag(words)
     33         for (word, type) in tags:

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)
   1287     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
   1288         last_break = 0
-> 1289         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
   1290             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
   1291             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thankyou

Comment: @1688694 I would like you to help me with your code. I will use it in my project but have the error. Can you help me, please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I see here.
First, about the error:
it occurs because you are passing `sentence` variable which is a list to `word_tokenize` which expects string ("asd") or object (a class instance, MyClass for example).

Second, you are passing `sentence` to `word_tokenize`  and by the look of your iteration you probably want to pass `sent` ?

If i'm wrong just ignore second advice.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the type of your `sentences` variable is not string or bytes, as expected. I don't know what value (type) is returned by the call to `sent_tokenize(data)`.

A dirty way to check the type of the sentences variable is to use
`print(type(sentences))` after the call to sent_tokenize.

Comment: @14129578 I print the type of (sentences ) >>> result is (<class 'list'>). How can I change it? thank you

Comment: @Marymahmed there are plenty of ways to change the type of something, but that probably won't solve your problem. Your for-loop suggests that you're trying to pass something else to `word_tokenize`. Did you intend to pass `sent` instead, perhaps?

Comment: @14129578 I want to lemmatize all words in sentences(CSV file) for our goal to reduce the frequency of words. But I don't know the way is right. thanks.